# Web push notification in Windows Desktop

Tags: windows, push-notification

Referring to this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/ I was able to integrate this with my web app and send push messages to my web app. On Mac(Chrome) i was able to push notifications even when the browser was closed.
But when I opened my web app on windows machine (Chrome), the push notifications appear only when the browser tab is open.
Am I missing something. How can I push notifications on Windows even if the browser is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive) JavaScript client to receive a message in the background.